# How to increment inside .map() in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I would like to increment salary number inside map function.

My code is currently working but I would like to know is this a correct way to increment number in React or what is the better method or how else should I do it?

find below the code so far

```
const users = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: "Tiger Nixon",
    salary: 320800,
    age: 61,
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: "Garrett Winters",
    salary: 170750,
    age: 63,
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: "Ashton Cox",
    salary: 86000,
    age: 66,
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    name: "Cedric Kelly",
    salary: 433060,
    age: 22,
  }
]
```

```
const [salary, setSalary] = useState(users)

const incrementSalary = (employeeSalary) => {
  salary.map(x => 
    x.salary === employeeSalary? {...salary, salary : x.salary += 1} : x 
  )
  setSalary([...salary])
}

return (
  <tbody>
    {salary.map((employee) => (
      <tr key={employee.id}>
        <th>{employee.id}</th>
        <td>{employee.name}</td>
        <td>{employee.age}</td>
        <td>
          <button>
            -
          </button>
          <span>{employee.salary}</span>
          <button onClick={() => incrementSalary(employee.salary)}>
            +
          </button>
        </td>
      </tr>
    )}
  </tbody>
```

Comment: No. `setSalary(salary.map(x) => x.salary === employeeSalary? {...salary, salary : x.salary  + 1} : x )` is one correct way. [`map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) returns a new array, please read the documentation. If you don't want the loop to return anything, use `forEach`, but it's usually better to default to immutable editing (using `+` instead of `+=`)

Comment: That's really awkward. Why not alter the array through the index from (`Array#find`)[https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find] and re-set the state?

Comment: TRY: 
```let employeeSalary = 10
setSalary(emps => {
   return emps.map(emp => {
    emp.salary === employeeSalary ? {...emp, salary: emp.salary + 1} : emp
})
})```

Comment: You really will want to pass the employee object whose salary should be incremented, not a salary number to increment the salaries of *all* employees with that salary value

Answer (score 0):

No, doing `x.salary += 1` mutates the existing state.

The correct way is to apply the immutable update patten: shallow copy all state, and nested state, that is being updated. You should also use a functional state update to correctly update from the previous state instead of whatever the current state value is that is closed over in callback scope.

You will also want to use an id or some other GUID to uniquely identify the employee element object you want to increment the salary property of.

Example:

```
const incrementSalary = (employeeId) => {
  setSalary(salary => salary.map(employee => 
    employee.id === employeeId
      ? {
        ...salary,
        salary: employee.salary + 1
      }
      : x 
  ));
};
```

...

```
{salary.map((employee) => (
  <tr key={employee.id}>
    <th>{employee.id}</th>
    <td>{employee.name}</td>
    <td>{employee.age}</td>
    <td>
      <button>-</button>
      <span>{employee.salary}</span>
      <button onClick={() => incrementSalary(employee.id)}>
        +
      </button>
    </td>
  </tr>
)}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's silly to map over the whole array to increment one number. `map` takes a second parameter - the index of the array.

This is the 'proper' way with immutability.

```
const defaultUsers = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: 'Tiger Nixon',
    salary: 320800,
    age: 61,
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: 'Garrett Winters',
    salary: 170750,
    age: 63,
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: 'Ashton Cox',
    salary: 86000,
    age: 66,
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    name: 'Cedric Kelly',
    salary: 433060,
    age: 22,
  },
];

export default function App() {
  const [users, setUsers] = useState(defaultUsers);

  const incrementSalary = (index) => {
    setUsers((prevUsers) => {
      const newUsers = [...prevUsers];
      newUsers[index] = {
        ...newUsers[index],
        salary: newUsers[index].salary + 1,
      };
      return newUsers;
    });
  };

  return (
    <tbody>
      {users.map((employee, index) => (
        <tr key={employee.id}>
          <th>{employee.id}</th>
          <td>{employee.name}</td>
          <td>{employee.age}</td>
          <td>
            <button>-</button>
            <span>{employee.salary}</span>
            <button onClick={() => incrementSalary(index)}>+</button>
          </td>
        </tr>
      ))}
    </tbody>
  );
}
```

Stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-a9rsnm?file=App.tsx

---

This is the faster way that gets you flamed by other React devs.

```
const defaultUsers = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: 'Tiger Nixon',
    salary: 320800,
    age: 61,
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: 'Garrett Winters',
    salary: 170750,
    age: 63,
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: 'Ashton Cox',
    salary: 86000,
    age: 66,
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    name: 'Cedric Kelly',
    salary: 433060,
    age: 22,
  },
];

export default function App() {
  const users = useRef(defaultUsers).current;
  const [_, forceUpdate] = useReducer((x) => x + 1, 0);

  const incrementSalary = (index) => {
    users[index].salary++;
    forceUpdate();
  };

  return (
    <tbody>
      {users.map((employee, index) => (
        <tr key={employee.id}>
          <th>{employee.id}</th>
          <td>{employee.name}</td>
          <td>{employee.age}</td>
          <td>
            <button>-</button>
            <span>{employee.salary}</span>
            <button onClick={() => incrementSalary(index)}>+</button>
          </td>
        </tr>
      ))}
    </tbody>
  );
}
```

Stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-f3rvaa?file=App.tsx

Comment: If you think iterating the entire array is silly just to update one element just wait until you find out what `[...prevUsers]` does.

Comment: @DrewReese I know what it does, I'd personally just mutate the state myself :P. Still saves you from doing the equality comparison at every index.

Comment: Ah, I see what you are trying to say then. O(n) operations is still O(n) though, so no ground breaking performance boosts to be gained here. Shallow copying the array then updating by a specific index is an alternative solution that works.

Comment: Yeah, let's be honest they're both slow af when you consider JS garbage collection. I'd personally just mutate the object in the original array, then force a rerender. I get Immutability has its benefits but most of the time I find it just complicating code and slowing it down.